# Column classification in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a matlab program to divide a column vector in to 4 types as per value. for example I have marks column matrix(100,1) now i want another matrix class to distribute this mark in to distinction, first class, second lass etc grade

Comment: Do you have tried any code in this week ?

Comment: Please tell what you already have tried. See: [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't have code with me. I am new to MATLAB

Comment: How do you determine these classes? For example, how do we tell if a mark is in first class?

Comment: Hi Beaker, For example Marks of students are ranging from 0 to 100 for 100 students. I want to classify those students in to fail, past class, second class, first class, distinction grades. Lets say 0 to 39 fail, 40 to 50 past class, 51 to 60 are second class, 61 to 74 first class, above 75 are distinction.

Comment: And you are unable to tell if an element of a vector is greater than or equal to 75?

Answer (score 0):

You want the histcounts() function.

from MATLAB help:

```
 [N,EDGES] = histcounts(X,EDGES), where EDGES is a vector, specifies the
  edges of the bins.
```

So something like

```
 [N, EDGES] = histcounts(marks, [0 40 51 61 75 100])
```